# How to Make google Show My website pages in the way I want

Tags: seo, google

Let us take an exapmle of ebay.
[image]

As you can see in image when I search for ebay it also shows subpages like Deals,GlobalEasybay and etc..For my site also this happens but the problem is that I don't have any control over it.It displays random sub-pages.My First question How I can control this.
Second You can see on the right column of my screenshot ,there is a nice presentation on ebay with a picture and rescent posts...How I can make something like this on my website?

Answer (score 2):

You can control which site sitelinks appear by demoting the 'random' ones you don't want appearing:

[sitelinks and how to demote them.](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en)

The info on the right is part of what Google calls ['knowledge graph'](http://ww.google.com/insidesearch/features/search/knowledge.html). These boxes generally appear for well known search phrases and brand names.

How ever you can try to prepare your site for the knowledge graph by improving your brand. You can do this by using structured mark up such as [linking your site to your company Google + page](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1708844?hl=en), adding [mark up on your sites logo](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com.au/2013/05/using-schemaorg-markup-for-organization.html), as well as other [structured mark up and rich snippets.](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/99170?hl=en) However, unless you are a well known brand, it it isn't very likely you will feature in the knowledge graph